Can "a tissue" be called a handkerchief or hanky?
In Cambridge dictionary,

hanky=a handkerchief (= square piece of cloth or paper used
for cleaning the nose and drying the eyes)

I thought a handkerchief was always made of cloth.

a tissue: [countable] a piece of soft paper, used especially as a
handkerchief


Say my friend has a box of tissue in front of me.
Can I say "May I have a hanky/handkerchief"?

I am British. When I was a kid, people called one of those things 'a paper hanky', but that may be thought a bit childish, and some people might prefer 'a tissue'. Some people may even say 'a Kleenex' even if they are not that brand. 'a hanky' is OK; you can leave off the word 'paper' in that situation. Note that it is a box of tissues.

In the US, a tissue is paper and a hanky/handkerchief is cloth. Never heard "a paper hanky".  It is "a box of tissues" in the plural here.   We use Kleenex the same as in the UK.  Could you hand me a kleenex?   Add a box of kleenex to the shopping list.

BTW, American paper companies are careful to term them facial tissues. Likely, an advertising study found that had the most positive connotation. In conversation, I cannot remember anyone, ever using that full name. Euphemisms abound - e.g., toilet, where toilet originally meant any article used when dressing.

Say: “Can I have a tissue?”  Refer to the box as a “tissue box”.

Lots of factors could influence answers here, such as age, regional dialects etc.
Speaking as a native British English speaker from Gen X, I grew up with cloth handkerchiefs being called 'hankies'. What we now usually refer to as 'tissues' were commonly called paper hankies by those around me some 40 years ago.
However, your post made me realise I haven't heard 'paper hanky' in a very, very long time. These days, we do call them "tissues". Meanwhile, in the USA, it is well-known that a tissue is commonly referred to as a kleenex after the popular brand, even when the tissues are not made by that manufacturer, a phenomenon sometimes known as genericisation.

A regular item on our shopping lists is a pack of Kleenex Balsam paper hankies, usually abbreviated to just 'PHs'.
